# Выбрать где сумма больше 500

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как отобразить, для каких фирм сумма по всем заказам больше 500?

Так выводит общую сумму по всем фирмам:

```
SELECT SUM(zakaz.price) AS "Сумма заказа", firma.fname AS "Название фирмы", COUNT(zakaz.codf) AS "Количество заказов"
FROM firma 
INNER JOIN zakaz ON zakaz.codf = firma.codf 
GROUP BY firma.fname
```

Пробую сделать так, но выдает ошибку:

```
SELECT SUM(zakaz.price) AS "Сумма заказа", firma.fname AS "Название фирмы", COUNT(zakaz.codf) AS "Количество заказов"
FROM firma 
INNER JOIN zakaz ON zakaz.codf = firma.codf  
WHERE SUM(zakaz.price) > 500 
GROUP BY firma.fname
```

Ошибка:

> Статистическое выражение не может использоваться в предложении WHERE, если оно не содержится во вложенном запросе предложения HAVING или в списке выбора, и столбец, подвергаемый статистической обработке, не является внешней ссылкой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо так:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(zakaz.price) AS "Сумма заказа", 
    firma.fname AS "Название фирмы", 
    COUNT(zakaz.codf) AS "Количество заказов"
FROM firma 
INNER JOIN zakaz ON zakaz.codf = firma.codf  
GROUP BY firma.fname
HAVING SUM(zakaz.price) > 500
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает)

Comment: Пожалуйста. Не относится к вопросу, но не рекомендуется использовать в модели данных два языка, или zakaz.cena, или order.price.

Comment: @ 0xdb, в задание такие переменные указаны. Можно вам еще один вопрос?

Comment: Задание составлено с не критической ошибкой. Какой?

Comment: @ 0xdb, наверно нужно код скинуть. Я добавлю в вопросе. В общем вывожу список данных из трех таблиц. Но нужно вывести только тех, кто входит во все группы. Пробовал как и в этом примере использовать HAVING, но не удачно

Comment: В этот вопрос не надо, против правил, получите минуса, задавайте новый.